# dropdown list for string in my module

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to create a dropdown list for the attribute City in my view. I defined the City in my Module as:

`public string City { get; set; }`

In my Controller

`ViewBag.City = new SelectList(db.Indviduals, "City","City");`

In my View

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownList("City", String.Empty)    
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem now is that the drop-down list contains ALL the Cities names from my database with redundancy. How can I show Unique list of cities names and then Pass the selected Value back to the Module ?

Comment: . You appear to getting the list of cities for an unrelated table. Do you have a table named Cities that store all available cities? Note you need to give your model property and the ViewBag property different names.

Answer (score 0):

Is db.Individuals IEnumerable? You can use the Distinct() method here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I tried but i couldn't because its not  IEnumerable :'( and i am totally new to asp.net

Comment: what kind of object is it?

Comment: Yeah then I would try to fire up those entities like this: var ind = db.Individuals.AsEnumerable().Distinct() then set that to the DS for the SelectList